# How do I fix this error with BRMS, Compilers, and Build tools

Tags: r, clang++, brms

I was running these models fine before I updated R and everything broke.

Everytime I attempt to run the model now a popup window appears saying

"Building R package from source requires installation of additional build tools.

Do you want to install the additional tools now?"

I have tried clicking ok and cancel and both result in the error:

```
Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  /usr/local/clang7/include/c++/v1/cstdlib:119:9: error: no member named 'strtoul' in the global namespaceusing ::strtoul;      ~~^fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]20 errors generated.make: *** [file1d036a27f010.o] Error 1
```

When Run the following lines however I get falses saying that it couldn't install everying:

```
> # We can check if Xcode CLI is present using:
> macrtools::is_xcode_cli_installed()
[1] FALSE
> 
> # We can verify gfortran is present as well
> macrtools::is_gfortran_installed()
[1] TRUE
```

Here is my R version:

```
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16) -- "Beagle Scouts"
Copyright (C) 2023 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
```

I have reinstalled R, Rstudio, stan, and Rtools. In addition I have installed: "oatless-mac/macrtools" and macrtools::macos_rtools_install().

Comment: You might be better off asking at the stan forum: discourse.mc-stan.org . In my experience they generally reply fast and have an better idea of how to troubleshoot.